# How to send an array of arrays in JSON using JSON.stringify while there is no key

Tags: node.js, curl, scikit-learn

This is kind of a basic question for part of you but I'm less familiar with JSON payload spec.
I was trying to execute an example which I foiund with the following curl:

curl -i   --header "Content-Type: application/json"   --request POST   --data '[[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2]]'   http://localhost:5000/predict

The operation works well although I haven't understood what kind of json payload is this:
[[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2]]

I'm familiar with a mapping key value when handling JSON payload, so what kind of key is being passed here? and why isn't this payload surrounded with '{}'

I'm asking since I want to use this payload to build a js script that will send this payload using JSON.stringify but I can't figure out how to pass the mentioned payload properly:

```
  var payload = JSON.stringify({
     [[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2]]
  });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't always need key value pairs is JSON. When the top level is [] and not {}, it is a case of JSONArray/Collection. This array can have numbers/strings/other JSON objects or other JSON Arrays. JSON.stringify([[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2]]) will work fine giving you '[[5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2]]'.

Answer (score 2):

Your payload is a (two-dimentional) array, which is not an object, hence no key, but is a valid JSON resource. So you can post it as is to API provided you write the correct syntax:

```js
 var payload = JSON.stringify(    // { <= remove the enclosing braces here as it's not an object
     [[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2]]
  );
```

A better practice to make your payload more robust (if you also handle the backend API) is to embed the array inside a wrapper object (with the benefit of compatibility with some APIs that has problem with top-level JSON array, and the ability to add more options or metadaa to your payload).

```js
 var payload = JSON.stringify( 
    {
       data: [[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2]],
       options: { }
    }
 );
```